# Cloudera Manager Installer fails to run on CentOS 6.2 32bit

Tags: cloudera

Though CentOS 6.2 32bit is on the list of supported operating systems, Cloudera manager installer fails to start saying "cannot execute binary file" 
It seems this installer doesn't support 32bit platforms any-longer. 
ANyone knows way around?

Answer (score 1):

64-bit is required, yes.

For further questions you may want to consider posting on [Cloudera's own forum](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/bd-p/CMInstall) on this subject.